# new line in popup box in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using the below code to generate pop up once clicked on the row of a GridView.

```
string ky = "Hello World"
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Popup", "alert('This is alert Message from C#')", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Popup", "alert('"+ky+"')", true);
```

and it is working fine.

when i insert new line character it doesn't  work,

```
string ky = "Hello \nWorld"
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Popup", "alert('This is alert Message from C#')", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Popup", "alert('"+ky+"')", true);
```

i want to see it as

Hello

World

also is there any way to design the popup box too.

Comment: Did you try `\r\n` to insert a new line?

Answer (score 2):

Change your string to

> string ky = "Hello \\nWorld"

double \ seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

a minor mistake.

```
string ky = "Hello \nWorld"
```

only need to put @ before "Hello \nWorld"

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, not with `\n`

Comment: it worked for me. \n works as new line operator in both .net and javascript.